# How to set div absolute position from the parent div

Tags: css-position

I need to output a number of divs that contain child divs that are poistioned absolutely:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
     Some content 1.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
     Some content 2.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
     Some content 3.
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

But my trouble is the child divs are stacking on top of each other, I'd like them to be displayed vertically, one after another.  I can do this by specifying a height for the parent div:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

But is there a way of doing it without specifying a height?

I've created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/n38546ca/1/

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a (padding-top: 50px;) to .parent div

`.parent {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
     padding-top: 50px;
}`